# Errors while importing pydot

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import pydot

graph=pydot.Dot(graph_type='graph')

for i in range(3):
    edge=pydot.Edge("king","lord%d" % i)

    graph.add_edge(edge)

vassal_num=0
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(2):
        edge = pydot.Edge("lord%d" %i ,"vassal%d" %vassal_num)
        graph.add_edge(edge)
        vassal_num=vassal_num + 1
```

The error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/tanvi/PycharmProjects/untitled1/plottree.py", line 3, in <module>
graph=pydot.Dot(graph_type='graph')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Dot'
```

Comment: see error message: it is not problem with import . It is problem with your code.

Comment: did you  name some file `pydot.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

pydot allows to process dot language files. If you want to create a graph from a prexisting dot file, you must add the file name, see [this](http://nullege.com/codes/search/pydot.Dot) for more details; but if you want to create an empty graph and custumize it (as it could be understood from your following code lines), you should consider networkx package.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot.